# REGEXP Help - Oracle Pass Through Query

Tags: regex, oracle, pass-through

Currently working in Microsoft Access, writing a PTQ to an Oracle Data Warehouse.

One of the fields is a description field which holds alphanumeric strings. Sometimes all characters, sometimes the inclusion of a 9 digit number.
What I want to be able to do is if there is a 9 digit number, to select it from that description field and create a new field with it.

```
SELECT description
     REGEXP_SUBSTR( * here goes the reg exp * ) "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
FROM myTable

REGEXP_SUBSTR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from
(
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR("desc",'\d{9}') REGEXPR_SUBSTR FROM temp1 
)
where REGEXPR_SUBSTR is not null;
```

Thil will work perfectly. It rejects nulls and only accept 9 digits. Last answer I was writing in hurry. Mi scuzi :)

Comment: This did work perfectly. Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not have SQLDeveloper or sqlplus to check it but let me try:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR(descritpion,'\d{0,9}') "REGEXPR_SUBSTR" FROM myTable
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working fully - it doesn't bounce back any errors, but it is returning a ton of blank rows and then rows with any # of digits in them. Would you be able to help me think of a better way to secure grabbing just the string of 9 numbers and putting it into its own column?

Sorry for being so needy - I am really stuck on this.